# Recursively get full path (parents hierarchy) of a given node in a nested object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need a typescript function to recursively get the full path (parent hierarchy) of a given node by passing its value.

Let's say I have an array of objects like this:

```
items = [{
        value: 2,
        text: "Name 2",
        children: [{
            value: 7,
            text: "Name 7",
            children: [{
                    value: 10,
                    text: "Name 10",
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    value: 11,
                    text: "Name 11",
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    value: 12,
                    text: "Name 12",
                    children: [{
                        value: 13,
                        text: "Name 13",
                        children: [{
                                value: 14,
                                text: "Name 14",
                                children: []
                            },
                            {
                                value: 15,
                                text: "Name 15",
                                children: []
                            }
                        ]
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        value: 16,
        text: "Name 16",
        children: [{
            value: 17,
            text: "Name 17",
            children: [{
                    value: 18,
                    text: "Name 18",
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    value: 19,
                    text: "Name 19",
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
];
```

Let's say I want to get the full path of node with value=19 by calling a function.

```
getPath(items, 19);
```

The expected result could be either returning only values of parent nodes

```
[16, 17, 19]
```

or array of objects as bellow:

> [{
>                   value: 16,
>                   text: "Name 16"
>               },
>               {
>                   value: 17,
>                   text: "Name 17"
>               },
>               {
>                   value: 19,
>                   text: "Name 19"
>               }
>       ]

Thanks,

Comment: what goes wrong with your code?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the code that you already have and point out where it does not work.

Comment: @NinaScholz nothing wrong! I just need a function how to get full path of a given node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help

```
const items = [{
    value: 2,
    text: "Name 2",
    children: [{
        value: 7,
        text: "Name 7",
        children: [{
            value: 10,
            text: "Name 10",
            children: []
        },
        {
            value: 11,
            text: "Name 11",
            children: []
        },
        {
            value: 12,
            text: "Name 12",
            children: [{
                value: 13,
                text: "Name 13",
                children: [{
                    value: 14,
                    text: "Name 14",
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    value: 15,
                    text: "Name 15",
                    children: []
                }
                ]
            }]
        }
        ]
    }]
},
{
    value: 16,
    text: "Name 16",
    children: [{
        value: 17,
        text: "Name 17",
        children: [{
            value: 18,
            text: "Name 18",
            children: []
        },
        {
            value: 19,
            text: "Name 19",
            children: []
        }
        ]
    }]
}
];

function getPath(items, val) {
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        const item = items[i];
        if (item.value !== val) {
            if (item.children) {
                const path = getPath(item.children, val);
                if (path) {
                    path.unshift(item.value);
                    return path;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return [item.value];
        }
    }
}

console.log(getPath(items, 19));
```

Here's the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/chk8bntf/1/) for it